# Why is my Xperia U slow?

Tags: performance, sony-xperia-u

I have a Sony Xperia U running Android 4.0.4 ICS. The problem is that it runs really slowly. It is particularly bad while multi-tasking. While listening to music, if I get a phone call, it hangs. Vibrator starts but the ringtone doesn't. The "Incoming Call" screen doesn't come up, etc.

Has anyone used this phone with Gingerbread? If so, how was their experience?

I followed the steps in [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32734/why-is-my-phone-slow), but my Battery Monitor says 43% Screen and 23% Android OS, which isn't really helpful! Are there any particular apps that are responsible for this?

Why is ICS slow on this device? I mean, 1.0 GHz dual core and 512 MB of RAM is not less!

edit: The first thing I did after buying it was to upgrade it to ICS via Sony PC Companion. The phone has been like this ever since. I phoned Xperia Support and also did a Firmware Repair (again via PC Companion) and a Factory Reset, but it's no use.

Comment: You neither specified if it was slow from the beginning, nor did you say if you maybe overloaded it with too many apps automatically running in background (you might want to [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/48649/edit) your question and update these details). Another source you might wish to consult: [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35367/16575)

Comment: Thanks @Izzy, but my phone isn't rooted, and I regularly Wipe App Cache!

Comment: This sounds familiar, in short, ICS on the Xperia line of devices, do eventually crawl down to slowness (have Xperia Mini 2011 model), in the end I had to unlock it, and flash a newer ROM on to it, its common enough on those 2011 devices that had gingerbread and upgraded to ICS...